# What does the cp in java -cp ... mean in a unix script?

Tags: java, unix

I'm debugging a unix script.   It makes a call to a java program with an option of -cp.   Does anyone know what that does?   I've never seen the -cp option before. Nor am I able to google an answer.  It looks like this:

```
java -cp ../myboot.jar -Djava.security.policy=$SOME_POLICY...
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)

Comment: try `java --help` or `java -help`. That's really basics.

Comment: I upvoted, because the `man` page for java does not clearly state it

Answer (score 3):

It's the shortcut for classpath ;)

Answer (score 3):

From

Windows:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Unix:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html

> -cp classpath
>
> Specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to search for class files. Separate class path entries with semicolons (;). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable

Comment: OP is on `unix`. While you are right, it is taken from the documentation for windows.